# Detect service which is trying to access MySQL database with root privileges

Tags: mysql, wordpress, brute-force-attacks

I have a server with MySQL database which is accessible by WordPress. In every 1-2 seconds I see the following in MySQL error.log

`[Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'`

There is no password attempt involved as I see it, but my root user has password set.

I am guessing this is some kind of brute force attack. The problem is that I cant figure out which service or script is trying this? My WordPress installation is not using root as user, and from what I saw in one plugin that may be susceptible to it, all SQL queries are in prepared statements.

I have tried tcpdump to sniff packets sent to local port on 3306 but it gave me nothing. How can I find which service or script is trying to access it? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

"localhost" implies a "socket" connection, no TCP/IP involved, hence `tcpdump` is useless.  The presumed hacker has already logged into your server.

Case 1, some program on your machine:  `ps` ("task manager") lists all the programs.  "lsof" is another tool.  (Neither of these is very practical since they both give huge lists.)

Case 2, an outside hacker:  Look for logins.  Look for shell scripts running in `ps`.  Meanwhile, add/strengthen all logins to the machine.

Comment: The only user logged in (I check in with `who -H`) is my own, so I doubt they got access. `/var/log/auth.log` is not showing any users except mine that I should consider danger. And I changed my password, but still it happens.

Comment: @AleksandarAndrijevic - A hacker will login, try to access the database, and logout in only a fraction of a second.  Don't expect them to wait around until you catch them.

Comment: Check the rest of the logins -- root, admin, and various admin-like "users" supporting various apps.  But don't blindly change passwords of logins you don't understand; you could break apps.

Comment: I will try to first disable for a minute Apache server for WP, to check if there are maybe some script injection taking place that can cause this. Then I will check logins. Thanks.

Comment: I disabled Apache service for 1-2 minutes and entries in error log for MySQL stopped. So I better check my instance of WordPress to see if there is some script wrong.

Comment: @AleksandarAndrijevic - Good.  When you get more details, I suggest you write a Question about it, then Answer your own question with what you found.  (Yes, self-answered questions are acceptable.)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not an WordPress instance, but another folder. In there was a valid script for forum which on old platform used root user, for unknown reason.

Changed user and now is OK. Thanks for all your help :)